# Vite-plugin-checker not recognizing errors when running the application

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vite

Since Vite is not able to recognize Typescript errors, I want the Vite-plugin-checker to check them for me while developing. Following the documentation, I installed as dev dependency:

```
"vite-plugin-checker": "^0.5.6",
"vue-tsc": "^1.2.0"
"typescript": "^5.0.3",
```

Then, in my `vite.config.ts`, I use the plugin:

```
import checker from 'vite-plugin-checker'

    plugins: [
      vue(),
      checker({typescript: true, vueTsc: true})
    ]
```

But when I run the application, it doesn't recognize any error. If I run it in build mode, it does. What's the problem here?

Comment: Did you import it well in your vite config ? `import checker from 'vite-plugin-checker';`
If yes, can you try to install it as a dependency to see if it changes anything

Comment: I tried to install it as dependency, but nothing changed

Comment: Can you share the error message?

Comment: There is no error. It simply doesn't show anything in the console or in the UI

Comment: Does everything work correctly without the `vite-plugin-checker` plugin? Is it necessary to use `typescript` and `vueTsc` keys simultaneously?

Comment: I think you should use only vueTsc, here is an example with vue3 : 

[Example Vue3 + Checker](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-e8pddl?file=package.json)

I also think that you should try to downgrade typescript, maybe it is not compatible with the 5.0.

If all of this not work, try to compare your tsconfig.json.